# Carousel responsiveness breaks when adding <p> to <div>

Tags: css, carousel

I'm trying to make a carousel that includes an actors picture, name, and character name. I based the code off another carousel on the site that works good but only includes pictures. When I add a <p> tag to a carousel item it stops being responsive and sometimes stops working all together.

Adding word-break helps a bit even if nothing is overflowing. In this case it stops being responsive at 4 items. This isn't ideal though as names/character names look a bit funny when split on different lines.

[Here's a codepen showing the problem.](https://codepen.io/SpawnBot/pen/mdQPWLV) Initially the text is hidden so you can see how it should work. Once an item gets too small it should move to the next slide.

Here the css:

```
.item p {
  /* kinda works with word-break, doesn't work at all without */
/*   word-break: break-all; */
  
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 8px;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(22, 22, 22);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.posters {
  --posters-displayed: 0;
  --scroll-index: 0;
  
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--scroll-index) * -100%));
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% / var(--posters-displayed));
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
}

.item .name {
  padding: 16px 0 6px 0 ;
}

.item .character {
  display: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #a7a7a7;
  padding-bottom: 16px
}

.nav-left,
.nav-right {
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid rgb(82, 80, 79);
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px;
}

.nav-left:hover,
.nav-right:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.nav-left {
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.nav-right {
  right: 0;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

Inside the carousel is:

```
<div className="posters">
    {data.map((actor) => {
        return (
            <div className="item">
                <img
                  src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300${actor.profile_path}`}
                  alt=""
                />

                <p className="name">{actor.name}</p>
                <p className="character">{actor.character}</p>
              </div>
        );
    })}
</div>
```

And --posters-displayed is calculated with
`Math.ceil(clientWidth / 250)` that reruns when resizing.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.